# Parse the regular expression itself and extract required parts

Tags: php, regex

I have a legacy code, that uses regular expressions to search for certain text patterns within large texts and replace them with links. These expressions have numerous optional parameters, such as

```
(free.?)?(online.?)?Blackjack
```

To speed things up I want to do a quick check with plain old strpos and look for required part of the expression (in this case 'blackjack') before running the lengthy replacement with preg_replace. Is there a way to process an expression itself and extract only required part(s)? I think it's done by yet another regular expression, but just in case, I'm using PHP.

Comment: Something like `(\([^)]*\)\?)` ?

Comment: I don't believe a regular expression for parsing regular expressions is a good idea. If it is possible (which is might be), it will not be faster than what your are currently doing. That being said, this question/answer might have some information about parsing a regular expression into parts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594135/a-parser-for-regular-expressions-in-php.

Comment: @Thomas this seems to select the optional parts :) but that's certainly a starting point for me, thanks!

Comment: @Scott point is, this 'keyword' can be saved along with the expression itself so the parsing will only occur once. thanks for the link, definitely a few useful snippets there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may replace your original optional parts from `(\([^)]*\)\?)` to blank, which will leave you with the required parts.